# Handling Response Output

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am new in Handling Response. While trying to fetch Values("title") in array, it is not working properly. It is updating Last Value alone in Array. How can I fetch all values("title") in an array? I even tried changing `lastObject` as `objectAtIndex:`

Below is my Response Output and Code.

```
NSDictionary *book = [[ jsonResults objectForKey:@"result"] lastObject];
NSArray *title = (NSArray *) [book objectForKey:@"title"];
```

**Response Output:**

```
{
    "result":
    [
       {
           "authors": [
                       "AuthRick"
                       ],
           "bno": 9280621999,
           "title": "Foo",
           "urlImage": "www.foo.hoo",
       },{
           "authors": [
                       "MaveRick"
                       ],
           "bno": 9951621988,
           "title": "Hoo",
           "urlImage": "www.foo.hoo",
       }
     ]
}
```

Comment: result key contains NSArray object or NSDictionay object?

Comment: { } is a bunch of key-value pairs (so your outer structure is an NSDictionary). [ ] is an NSArray of things (so the value of key `result` is an NSArray). Since you got an array, you have iterate to get each book (which is an NSDictionary). From that dict you can access the `title` value. Since that value is within quotes, it is an NSString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i look at this, this may suits this response,

```
NSMutableArray *titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
NSArray *resultArray = [ jsonResults objectForKey:@"result"];
for(NSDictionary *individualBookDictionary in resultArray)
{
  [titleArray addObject:[individualDictionary valueForKey:@"title"]];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try this..



NSDictionary *response; //getting your response as Dictionary,so keep response dictionary in response variable(i.e response dictionary)

    NSArray *arr =[response valueForKey:@"result"]; //get result Array

    for (int i=0; i<arr.count; i++) {

        NSLog(@"title--%@",[[arr objectAtIndex:i] valueForKey:@"title"]); //here your getting two titles of data


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the title field value in **title** array with below code :

```
NSArray *resultArray = [jsonResults objectForKey:@"result"];
NSMutableArray *title = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(NSDictionary *obj in resultArray)
{
  [arytitle addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"title"]];
}
```